# Are "œ" and "eu" pronounced the same in Parisian French?

Tags: prononciation

For instance, I hear "professeur" and "fleur" with the "eu" sound, not "œ".

Comment: By "œ" do you mean the [œ] phoneme or literally the ligature ?

Comment: I don't think there is a really pronounced "Parisian French" - there are regional accents in France, but Paris doesn't really have one as far as pronunciation is concerned - or if there is, it's not very pronounced at all.

Comment: @Frank That's a very parisian statement. Of course there is a Parisian accent. That's very noticeable when you have a different one.

Comment: It turns out that I am definitely not parisian at all :-) I couldn't tell a "Parisian accent" myself - I can recognize an _accent du sud_, sometimes an accent in Alsace, but after that, the other "accents" in France don't feel very pronounced to me. There can be slightly different expressions, and I'm not saying accents are not there, just that there is a real "common denominator" that makes les _quatre coins de l'hexagone_ mutually intelligible without any effort (if not speaking outright dialect).

Comment: Over my years studying French I have encountered a million and one sources supporting jilliagre's assertion. The number of times I have heard reference to a "Parisian accent" is quite, quite large.

Comment: @Frank You missed my point. "Parisian French" is used in English to define the accent used by the educated, middle and upper class French people living in Paris area or anywhere, when compared to Quebec accents but also the numerous ones used in the many other francophone locations, whether inside or outside Metropolitan France. Many French people, especially those having that "Parisian" accent, believe having it is equivalent to having no accent at all which is a little conceited imho. When I was a kid, I could spot people having that *accent parisien* in a matter of seconds ;-)

Comment: I'll see if youtube has examples of that "parisian accent" - that should be interesting.

Comment: J'ai trouvé ça: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Egrfsn2CU8E, et "l'accent" de Paris dans cette vidéo semble être le plus "neutre". Peut-être est-ce devenu le "défaut"? On peut évidemment dire que c'est aussi un "accent" comparé aux autres, mais il me semble que c'est "l'accent" que je n'ai pas besoin de faire d'effort pour comprendre. On me dit aussi que le français le plus "pur" serait celui de la vallée de la Loire plutôt que de Paris.

Comment: @redahabsinpeach - Je ne sais pas trop quel accent à Ginette. Ca sonne surtout assez vulgaire (bien sûr). Je ne suis peut-être pas très calé en accents après tout :-)

Comment: Et une autre vidéo, justement sur les "oe" à Paris: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7h1HE6KPO4

Comment: Un vidéo sur l'origine de l'accent Québecois et de l'accent parisien : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yESKzTPnHAg

Comment: @redahabsinpeach - oui peut-être, dans une des vidéos, un commentaire disait: "_c'est pas l'accent parisien, c'est l'accent bourge!_".

Comment: @Frank Il ne faut pas chercher le *Parisian French* très loin. Il suffit d'allumer la télévision française ou de regarder un film français. C'est l'accent « standard » ou prétentieusement « sans accent » qu'il faut acquérir si on ne l'a pas déjà quand on veut réussir dans la plupart des métiers de communication. Autrefois, surtout dans le midi, on disait « parler pointu » mais l'expression se perd, comme les accents régionaux en France et souvent ailleurs aussi. http://news.radins.com/actualites/les-accents-regionaux-voie-disparition,18727.html

Comment: C'est peut-être pour cela que j'ai réagi: parce que c'est l'accent _standard_. Ceci dit, il y a peut-être aussi des spécificités clairement parisiennes, mais pas "standard" ("bourge"?).

Comment: @Frank Il y a des phénomènes phonologiques qui sont absolument liés à Paris et qui s'estompent au fur et à mesure qu'on s'en éloignent. Les /R/ très spirants dans toutes les positions sauf /tR/ et l'insertion d'un /ə/ après les consonnes finales sont deux traits très saillants pour moi ("il est tard" prononcé /iletaʁ̞ə/)

Comment: @Frank On sort de la définition de *Parisian French* mais il y a une grande variété d'accents à Paris et autour. Beaucoup n'ont rien à voir avec l'accent « Auteuil / Neuilly / Passy ».

Comment: ... _tel n'est pas mon ghetto_ ;-)

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: "œ" and "eu" aren't the same, but "**œu**" and "**eu**" do make the same sounds. Exactly which sound depends on context, but the behaviour mostly overlaps between the two of them.

In Parisian French "professeur" and "fleur" both end with [œʁ], using the vowel [œ] as in "œuf".

[R-colouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel) likely comes into play. This is when an "r" modifies the vowel before it. Technically, as Wikipedia states, there's an actual change of vowel only in rare contexts — apparently you should only hear it in Québec French and then only in borrowings like "hamburger". But it would be fair to say that "r" *mildly affects* the quality of any vowel before it. The combination [œr] in particular can sound very odd to English ears, even though "œuf" doesn't raise any flags.

---

**Longer analysis**

When going from spelling to pronunciation, always keep a few terms in mind: [graphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) (letters/smallest indivisible combination of letters), [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) (underlying sound), and [phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)) (the different ways a single phoneme actually sounds in a particular context).

It requires a lot of analysis to tell which phoneme a particular letter combination is linked to — and even that would have to be qualified with "most of the time", because spelling isn't consistent in French. (Even if French is much more consistent than English!)

I'd hoped to just copy a previous analysis, e.g. on the Wikipedia [French phonology article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology)... but since I don't see this adequately treated there, here's my best shot after testing out some dictionary entries and trying to recall my linguistics education. :p

---

First of all, the two combinations we're comparing are "eu" and "œu". That's because "œ" behaves a lot like "e". It [came into the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92) as an attempt to spell the Greek [diphthong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) [oi̯] (similar to "boy"). However, its pronunciation "was reduced to a simple vowel ([[e]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_rounded_vowel)) in late Latin".

Being an attempt to render another language's sound, "œ" unsurprisingly has some inconsistent behaviour depending on which combinations it appears in — but then "e" on its own is also inconsistent. :) Luckily, we can reasonably hope that **"œu" behaves similarly to "eu".**

---

I would say that the two letter combinations both link to one phoneme, /ø/. That one phoneme, however, surfaces as either  [[ø]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_rounded_vowel) or  [[œ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_rounded_vowel) depending on the context.

Mostly, open syllables (syllables that end in a vowel) are realized as [ø]:

> pneu peu feu ceux yeux
>
> vœu nœud

And closed syllables (syllables that end in a pronounced consonant) are realized as [œ]:

> arroseur peur fleur fleuve
>
> œuvre sœur cœur mœurs mœuf œuf

However, there are some exceptions that trouble this analysis:

> arroseuse émeute *([ø] despite being closed syllables)*

Particularly interesting is this one, where the phonetic context is the exact same:

> **jeune** *([œ], as expected)* vs. **jeûne** *([ø])*

I haven't been able to find such exceptions with "œu", only with "eu". So that is probably a good hint that they can diverge sometimes.

The French phonology article also refers to "longer" syllables closed by a few specific consonants that are all voiced, which affect some similar vowel pairs in French. (The reason phones like [ø] and [œ] are linked to one phoneme is that they are very similar in pronunciation, sometimes differing only by whether the tongue is a little higher or farther forward.)

That might help to explain [ø/œ], but some of this data would still be hard to account for. For example, this group couldn't include both "arroseuse" ("long" syllable) and "émeute" ("short" syllable), nor would it explain "jeune" vs. "jeûne". To get a really robust analysis, we'd need to dig up more data.

---

Also, "œil" also has [œ], suggesting that "œ" followed by any vowel, not just "u", is pronounced [œ].

When *not* followed by another vowel, "œ" is often pronounced [e] as it was in late Latin, particularly in technical terminology (which often enters a language late and ends up using alternative phonology that hasn't seen centuries upon centuries of everyday use). For example:

> cœliaque cœlacanthe fœtus œsophage

There are always exceptions, such as the loanword "Gœthe" (with [ø], as pronounced in German).

---

Note that there is only one nasalized version of these two sounds: [œ̃]. Incidentally, in "Parisian" French, [this has merged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_French#cite_note-merger-5) with [[ɛ̃]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel). Thus, "brun" and "brin" are pronounced the same in Paris.

---

Remember that this is just a provisional analysis... if someone takes the time to find exceptions to base a rule on, or to find an article detailing this in a clearer way, I welcome the insight. :)

Comment: You should distinguish "œu" or "œ" when followed by the vowel ("i") which is always pronounced either [ø] or [œ], and "œ" followed by a consonant which, like "æ" (e.g. *læticia*)", is expected to be pronounced [e] in French.

Comment: It really boils down to "œ" being a variant of spelling "e", except in some loanwords like Gœthe. Btw, "fleuve" is /flœ:v/, not /flø:v/

Comment: @Eauquidort "œ" (but not "œu" or "œi") is more a variant spelling of "é", for example *économie* used to be spelt *œconomie*

Comment: It's much more accurate to the concensus on French phonolgy now. @jlliagre It can also be /ɛ/ in a closed syllable (œstrus). I deliberately glossed over the diacritic issue by considering /e/ and /ɛ/ as the core pronunciations of an orthographic "e" but i agree that's discutable

Answer (score 0):

[Here on Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92#Exemples_de_mots_fran.C3.A7ais_contenant_.C2.AB_.C5.93_.C2.BB)  is a short list of words that contain œ. It mentions that two pronunciations are prevalent for this "letter" : [[œ]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie) and [[ø]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie). You can listen to them on the linked pages.

Indeed, both sound a lot like "eu", which technically designates [ø] (per [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eu_(digramme))).

Comment: Therefore, if you ask whether "eu" should sound like [œ], the answer is **no**, "eu" should sound like [ø]. It is quite close though.