# Differences in pronunciation in dictionaries

Tags: prononciation, dictionnaires, ipa

Why there are differences in pronunciations descriptions in dictionaries? For example "heureux":

Larrouse: [ɶrø]
Wordreference: [øʀø]
Le Grand Robert: [œʀø]
Le Petit Robert: [øʀø]

These transcriptions have different sound realizations. Which one should be used.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two pronunciations are both of mainstream and standard. and these dictionaries also show standard ones. 
Source: TLFi-> heureux

Answer (score 2):

They are all actual existing variants. They do not prevent understanding so any of them can be used.

See also: [Are "œ" and "eu" pronounced the same in Parisian French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/24924/1109)

Comment: Thanks. Practical facets and our capacities aside, top best standard dictionaries show different transcriptions, my question goes for which one is the main stream.

Comment: There are regional and individual variations. Here are some examples : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/heureux#Prononciation

Comment: The answers is: these two pronunciations are both of mainstream and standard. these dictionaries also show standard ones. These have nothing to do with 'variation's in pronunciation which is true but undue here. The question did not look on the practical faces and the estimation of capabilities to match native speakers is totally unrelated. Source: TLFi-> heureux

Comment: There is no French standard (i.e. official) pronunciation in the first place. There is no single mainstream pronunciation either. What is mainstream somewhere is considered a strong accent elsewhere. Dictionaries pronunciations are informative, not normative. Vowels pronunciation belongs to a linear space, the realization of an *eu* by native French speakers can and does vary between [ɶ] and [ø].